# IS this question "hard science" tagged, or not? The interface shows conflicting information

Tags: support

in question: [How to avoid boats on a mainly oceanic world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/190903/how-to-avoid-boats-on-a-mainly-oceanic-world)

The question shows the pop-up box warning of HARD SCIENCE

.
.
.
Yet the actual tags do not include "hard science", only "science based"

The quest is really:
DO we obey the displayed tags at the bottom of a question, or the pop-up requirement for "Hard Science", when these two are in conflict?

[image]

Comment: Just closing this question does NOT answer it. The provided Dupilicate discusses how a user can remove their own "hard-science" popup. it does **********NOT********** say whether the pop-up must still be obeyed when present.

Comment: It explains the situation and how to handle it. No matter how many capital letters and *** you use

Comment: What "pop-up" are you referring to? The tags got edited and the pop-up got removed by Mods. What more do you want that wasn't addressed in the other query?

Comment: @elemtilas Rules state that we must respect tags. This question was NOT tagged with "hard science", but it DID, as my image shows, contain the pop-up requiring hard science. AT THE TIME THAT WAS SHOWING, was the question restricted to hard science or not? I know the popup was later removed by a mod, because i queried it. but at the time I posted this, there was conflicting instructions. so... are we supposed to obey the tags, or the pop-ups, or both, or neither?

Comment: You just answered your own question: 1. respect the tags (though feel free to question any tag when it doesn't seem to fit; 2. the pop-up box is a reminder that a "special" tag is in place; 3. just be aware that the pop-up is both placed and removed manually by the Mod Squod and there can be a delay in either action; 4. when in doubt, refer to Rule 1.  Generally speaking: if there's a conflict, you go with what the tags say, not what the pop-up says.  Kind of like when you're driving: there's a sign that says "STOP AHEAD"; you don't slam on the brakes in the middle of the road for this...

Comment: ...advisory sign.  You simply take note and keep on going until you get to the sign that says "STOP". Then you stop! Should the STOP sign be removed for some legit reason, and they forget to remove the "STOP AHEAD" sign, are you going to slam on your brakes for no reason?...

Comment: @elemtilas "1. Generally speaking: if there's a conflict, you go with what the tags say, not what the pop-up says" **thank you**, this is the clarity I was asking for.

Comment: Humans are imperfect, so there will always be a time between the moment a querent decides to remove the [tag:hard-science] tag and the Mods remove the "Hard Science" explanatory notice. Getting them programmatically associated is impossible as that's a system-wide enhancement. We get to just live with it. However, a notice is only explanatory. Nothing more. ***Tags are king.*** If there's no [tag:hard-science] tag, there's no hard-science expectation, notice or not. If you find such a case, you can help out by flagging the Q for the mods and asking for it to be removed.